# How to implement TreeMaps DrillDown on Button Click?

Tags: c#, wpf, treemap, drilldown

I am using the treemaps for an application development. The problem I am facing is that I want to use a button to remove the level I have traversed. I have tried but there is no use. I am new to WPF programming and I am not sure about all the methods that can be used. I have put a button and I have been able to retrieve the level number and reduce the level number onClick. but the level is the same. I used drilldown property for the tree maps. But I am not sure of  implementing it by use of a button. Sample is mostly preferred as a beginner. Hope for a reply sooner.

Scenario:-
I was using a squarified treemap for visualising a data that consisted of 4 levels. I drillDown the map to view certain details. For example, I have a world map that shows the continents separately. I have clicked on any of the continent, say Asia, I will get another level that shows the countries as a treemap level and further clicking on the country leads me to the cities or states. Like wise I can move backwards without an problem. Now, I am using a button to remove the levels I am currently located in. I am not able to do so and could you please help me with a code snippet for the button

Comment: What does it mean "remove the level I have traversed"?  Treemaps is a broadly defined visual technique, what is your implementation?  Too little information in your question for somebody to give a substantive answer.  Voting on this one as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: I was using a squarified treemap for visualising a data that consisted of 4 levels. I drillDown the map to view certain details. For example, I have a world map that shows the continents separately. I have clicked on any of the continent, say Asia, I will get another level that shows the countries as a treemap level and further clicking on the country leads me to the cities or states. Like wise I can move backwards without an problem. Now, I am using a  button to remove the levels I am currently located in. I am not able to do so and could you please help me with a code snippet for the button.

Comment: It's getting clearer.  Please take your comment and weave it back in to the question so that people don't have to read the comments to get the whole picture.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Gary. Could you be quick on the answer so that I can finish my work faster and may help to impress the boss!!!!!!

Comment: Vote retracted.  You're good.

Comment: Any update on this? I am also trying my level best to bring it out, but I am not getting into the exact route.

Comment: Any body there who can help me out from this? This is an urgent case and I could only bring the partial output which is not the desired one. I am almost there in my project. But this implementation is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I am partially there, but a detailed research will help me. It took a long time for me to settle in this.

private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        int level = TreeMap.Levels.Count;
        if (level >= 1)
        {
            TreeMap.Levels.RemoveAt(level-1);

        }


    }
```

This code can only be used to change the level, not the visual of the same level. It will not get you back to the desired screen, but you can notice the level change once you debug and use Watch.